Book/Sefarim recommendations that explore the deeper meaning of Eretz Yisrael?
Does anyone have any Book/Sefarim recommendations that explore the deeper meaning of Eretz Yisrael as a whole and/or specific places in Israel? The books can be in Hebrew or English.

Here's some great stuff from R DZ Hoffman https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/R._David_Zvi_Hoffmann/Bereshit/12.7#m6e0n6

As mentioned in my question (and answer) here, I would recommend reading the sefer "Tzion V'areha" (Hakdama, p. 9), which is a sefer that specifically talks about Eretz Yisroel by Rabbi Moshe Wolfson. Refer to the table of contents, where different subjects can be read:

The holiness of Eretz Yisroel
Fruits of the Land of Yisroel
The future of Yerushalayim (and that it will spread until Damascus)

It also explains the virtues of different, specific places in Eretz Yisroel, such as Teveriah (Tiberias/Galilee) and the Holy City of Yerushalayim.

Thank you for the suggestions!

Here are three books I think you will enjoy on this specific topic

Sacred soil by R Moshe Wolfson and Baila Vorhand, which describes the deeper meaning of the Land overall, specific cities and sacred places
Places in the Parasha by Prof. Yoel Elitzur where "he analyzes archaeological and linguistic findings, peruses historical sources, and explores the derivation and meaning of names – all in an attempt to offer geographic identifications and linguistic solutions to the riddles of the Tanakh. The Garden of Eden and the Ai, Goren Ha-Atad and Mount Sinai, Mount Gerizim and Mount Ebal, and even Azazel are some of the places discussed in the chapters of this book, presented in the order of the weekly parashot."
Excavating the Bible by Yitzhak Meitlis which describes archeological findings in relation to the Torah


Thank you for your recommendation

The Eim Habonim Smeichah is a classic on this. You can find it in English as well.
Rebbe Nachman miBreslov was very strong about Eretz Yisroel as well, and spoke about it often. His works contain much discussion about the importance and centrality of Eretz Yisroel to our existence as Jews. Along those lines Reb Noson miBreslov's student, R' Nachman Goldstein miTcherin, wrote a sefer which relates each of Rebbe Nachman's teachings to Eretz Yisroel. It's called Zimras Ha'aretz. What's nice about this edition as well is that it compiles all of those teachings of Rebbe Nachman - and also of Reb Noson - into a kuntres in the back half of the sefer, called Eretz Yisroel.
Sample of Zimras Ha'aretz:

Sample of kuntres Eretz Yisroel:


Thank you for your recommendation

Is Zimrat Ha'Aretz a translation of Rebbe Nachman: This Land Is My Land (History, Conflict and Hope in the Land of Israel)?

This Land is My Land is a great book written by R' Chaim Kramer from the Breslov Research Institute. I've never gone fully through it, but it discusses a lot of things unrelated to Rebbe Nachman's teachings on it. I would say it's a light introduction to Rebbe Nachman's hashkafah on Eretz Yisroel, but the kuntres Eretz Yisroel will give you a full picture - with lots of proofs as well ;) The Zimras Ha'aretz, on the other hand, is completely different from TLiML, as it is relating all of Rebbe Nachman's teachings - even those not related to Eretz Yisroel explicitly - back to Eretz Yisroel.

To clarify, Zimras Ha'aretz was written by R Nachman Goldstein who was a talmid of Reb Noson, so it was written around 200 years ago. Kuntres Eretz Yisroel is a compilation of quotes from Rebbe Nachman's and Reb Noson's sefarim, all of which were written over 200 years ago. So the book "This Land is My Land" is a digest of ideas gleaned from those sefarim written in a much more שווה לכל נפש sort of way.

Phenomenal. Thank you.
